# Collision callback function not called

Tags: unity-game-engine

i am bloody beginner with Unity and i am currently working on a 2D Brawler. The movement works perfectly but my colliders don't do what they should... I want to detect if two GameObjects Collide (Spear and Player2) and if the collide Player2s healthPoints should decrease by Spears AttackDamage.

The names of the GameObjects are also their tags. The Spears Prefab has following configuration: SpriteRendered(Material Sprites-Default), BoxCollider2D(Material None Physics Material 2D, IsTrigger(not activated), UsedByEffector(also not activated) Rigidbody2D(Kinematic, None Material, Simulated(Activated), KinematicContacts(activated), Standard configs for the rest))

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class SpearCtr : MonoBehaviour {

    public Vector2 speed;
    public float delay;
    Rigidbody2D rb; 

    void Start ()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rb.velocity = speed;
        Destroy(gameObject, delay);
    }
    void Update ()
    {
        rb.velocity = speed;
    }
}
```

The Players Configurations
The Spears Configurations
This was the code i have tried before

```
OnCollision2D(Collision2D target);
{
    if (target.gameObject.tag == "Spear")
    {
        hp = -1;
        if (hp <= 0)
        {
            alive = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone can tell me how to get this working
Thanks for all the answers 
(BTW sorry for my bad english I am austrian)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOd3a.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYiNt.png)

Comment: So from the things you tried does it just never detect any collision or is it when you detect a collision it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: It doesn`t even detect a collision

Comment: If you have the IsKinematic set to true it won't detect the collisions.

Comment: Btw you have `;` at the end of your `OnCollision2D(Collision2D target);` so it won't work for sure.

Comment: @CNuts That's not really the problem. It's the spelling

Comment: @JulianFuchs I've seen many questions about collisions not working and some of these are duplicates. I've decided to put together an answer that covers most likely reasons why they are not called. It is `OnCollisionEnter` not `OnCollision2D`. This I can use to close future similar questions.It is usually a spelling mistake.

Comment: @Programmer Ya i just realized that haha should of looked at that first. That would be a good idea. You should probably add the tables at the bottom of the manual  [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) It will help people understand what can collide with what.

Comment: I plan to do that too. I also plan to add the Trigger too. I am away from my computer now  and will do all those when I come back.

Comment: Ok it still doesnt work... but i was now able to post the pictures (just noticed that it didnt work yesterday) I hope someone is able to find the last mistake... But thank u all so much for answering my question u are all great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reasons why `OnCollisionEnter()` does not work:

**Collison**:

**1**.*[`Rigidbody`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html) or [`Rigidbody2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html) is not attached*.

At-least, *one* of the *two* GameObjects must have `Rigidbody` attached to it if it is a 3D GameObject. `Rigidbody2D` should be attached if it is a 2D GameObject/2D Collider.

**2**.*Incorrect Spelling*

You failed to spell it right. Its spelling is also case sensitive.

The correct Spellings:

*For 3D MeshRenderer/Collider*:

[`OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html)

[`OnCollisionStay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionStay.html)

[`OnCollisionExit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionExit.html)

*For 2D SpriteRenderer/Collider2D*:

[`OnCollisionEnter2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html)

[`OnCollisionStay2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionStay2D.html)

[`OnCollisionExit2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionExit2D.html)

**3**.Collider has `IsTrigger` checked. *Uncheck* this for the OnCollisionXXX functions to be called.

[image]

**4**.The script is **not** attached to any of the Colliding GameObjects. Attach the script to the GameObject.

**5**.You provided the wrong parameter to the callback functions.

*For 3D MeshRenderer/Collider*:

The parameter is `Collision` not `Collider`.

It is:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {}
```

**not**

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collider collision) {}
```

*For 2D SpriteRenderer/Collider2D*:

6.Both Rigidbody that collides has a `isKinematic` enabled. The callback function will not be called in this case.

**This is the complete collison table**:

[image]